# Page Class Suffix doesn't work

Tags: joomla-3.x

I want to add a custom CSS to a page of my website...
I have edited the Page class Suffix of the page I want to edit, but I dont know why, the class doesn't appear in the body when I go to that page...

How could I add a class to the body of the page I want to change...?

Comment: Just to clarify, the class does not appear in the body tag, it will appear within a `<div>` within the main content area.

Comment: If you look in the source for itempage, you'll find your page class appended to it. It's not helpful if you need the class for anything outside of the article content, but see below for my solution in that event.

Comment: I know this was asked really long time ago, but why do we need to alter Joomla code to implement page suffix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to add the page class to the body, then add this code above the doctype:

```
<?php
  $app = JFactory::getApplication();
  $menu = $app->getMenu()->getActive();
  $pageclass = '';

  if (is_object($menu))
    $pageclass = $menu->params->get('pageclass_sfx');
?>
```

And this code to your body

```
<body id="<?php echo $pageclass ? htmlspecialchars($pageclass) : 'default'; ?>">
```

Anything without a page class will use an id of "default", anything with the page class defined will appear as the id of the body. Obviously you can change that id to class if that's what you need.

Comment: Yeah, But I only want to add it to TWO pages of my website. Not to the body tag in general. I just want the class in the body tag in ONLY two pages.

Comment: Just don't style the default. Or rewrite the php so that it's an if statement, meaning if the page class is filled in, add it to the body, otherwise ignore it. If you don't attach any styles to the other ids, you won't have a problem.

Comment: And how can I do an if statement giving to the body a class depending on the page I am...

Comment: I don't know php man, I can't help you. But if you can see the url, you can write something like that. I'm telling you though, you don't need to be so specific. If all your pages have default in the id, and two other pages have custom ids, just style the custom pages differently and let the rest use your normal styles.

Comment: Here's an example of a site where we used this: http://integrityconsulting.ca - Just check the code for the body id, you'll see how it works.

Comment: It doesn't work. I wrote it in the supposed main php file where all the components are called...

Comment: Did you add the code above the doctype?

Comment: Forget it, I get it, thanks too much for your help

Answer (score 3):

Having read the comments, do as REactionFaye suggests, except for the last bit. You'll want your body tag to be:

```
<body <?php if ($pageclass != '') echo 'class="'.htmlspecialchars($pageclass).'"';?>>
```

In this case, the class attribute is only set for the menu items actually having a pageclass suffix configured.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to modify index.php because Joomla doesn't add the page class to the body element it adds it to the parent `<div>` for the view, e.g. com_content for articles. In index.php you need:

```
<body class="<?php echo $this->pageclass_sfx;?>"
```

You might also want to create a template override for the view type as well, to remove the page class from that, so it isn't duplicated within the document body.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, the Joomla `$pageclass` variable indicates that when creating a menu you need to give page class name under the page display option.

And call this in body tag:

```
<body class=" <?php echo $pageclass; ?>">
```

Note: When ever you create new menu, you need a separate class name in body tag, we need to add the page class.